# Magento keeps creating multiple indexes in Elasticsearch

Tags: reindex, elasticsearch, indexing

I have a couple Magento stores, and have them hooked up to an Elasticsearch server. On just one of the stores, it seems to regularly create new index names every day, which leads to overage issues with the ES hosting service. I can't figure out why this is happening.

I've had it working before where it creates a single index and just continues to update that regularly. But this seems to be abandon the old index and generates a new one under a new name. Also odd is that it is naming them even numbers.

mage_rs_product_1_v10   5.2MB

mage_rs_product_1_v12   3.6MB

mage_rs_product_1_v14   5.2MB

mage_rs_product_1_v16   3.7MB

mage_rs_product_1_v18   3.9MB

The latest one I presume is v18. Are all these indexes needed, or am I correct in that it is creating new ones and the older ones are obsolete? Is there a way to auto delete old indexes not being used when Magento creates a new one?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having similar issues to this, I've found my own answer.
The issue is that Magento when reindexing on schedule daily, fails to delete the old index from Elasticsearch because of snapshotting on the ES server.

cron.log:[2023-09-15 05:00:44] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"snapshot_in_progress_exception","reason":"Cannot delete indices that are being snapshotted: [[magento_index-29833]]. Try again after snapshot finishes or cancel the currently running snapshot."}],"type":"snapshot_in_progress_exception","reason":"Cannot delete indices that are being snapshotted:

Generally if this happens, the application should try again if returning a 400 error like this, but Magento does not. I'm not sure if this is fixed in some newer Magento's, or you just have to figure out how to change Snapshotting on Elasticsearch to not coincide with Indexing. Since I use a service, I need to see how to adjust the indexing time.